# Issue Invoking a context menu when an onClickListener is applied to an activity

Tags: android

Please find the code sample below:

```
    public class Abc extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private ListView displayList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        displayList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.addressbooklistview);
        addressbookAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,addressbookList);
        displayList.setAdapter(addressbookAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(displayList);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    { 
         Log.e("", "Entered Context Menu");
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.e("", "Click Detected");
    }

}
```

I am not able to invoke the context menu on long press.
Please let me know any solution for the same.

Comment: Did you try to call super.onClick(v) in your onClick implementation?

Comment: what should super.onClick() do as it is an interface and presumably has NO Super-implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem.  Originally the "show context menu" functionality was working, but when I added normal "click" functionality, the context menu no longer worked.

My problem was that I actually had the onClick() code on a TextView within the Listview item, not on the ListView itself.  Presumably, it was stealing the click from the listview.  To fix this, I removed that code, and in my Activity's onCreate method, I call setOnItemClickListener() for the ListView.  So now I have this:

```
// This creates the context menu functionality.
registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.list_item));

// This creates the click functionality for the listview item.
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // code here            
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly my problem. As a side effect, when you set the onClick of each item individually, you don't get the normal list selector background change when you click the item.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is stating explicitly that the longClick was not handled by adding a OnLongClickHandler to the view as well:

```
   view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            // do something
        }
    });
    view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false; // ignore and bubble up
        }
    });
```